# Condition to avoid [Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element'] when using XML page

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome-extension, innerhtml

Im working on a chrome extension project where I have a feature that injects a div into the current page via 'innerHTML'. This work fine on a page that is HTML, however when the page is an XML type (such as a VAST XML type), I get the following error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.`

My code is as follow:

```
function injectContextMenuContainer() {
  toolboxElement = document.createElement('div')
  toolboxElement.setAttribute('id', 'contextMenu-data-root') // root div
  // toolboxElement.setAttribute('class', 'close');
  document.body.appendChild(toolboxElement)

  // creates div unde root div
  toolboxElement.innerHTML = `
  <button id="closeButton"> &times; </button>
  <div id="contextMenu-data-container"></div>
  `

  // Assign listener to variable and add onclick function to close div
  const closeButton = document.getElementById('closeButton')
  closeButton.onclick = handleClose
}

function handleClose() {
  const containerElement = document.getElementById('contextMenu-data-root')
  containerElement.style.display = 'none'
}

 injectContextMenuContainer()
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a condition where i call the function, so I can only execute this function when the page is an HTML type, else do not execute.

Im having some issues finding the right approach to achieve this. The end goal will be for the function to NOT execute when the page is a vast XML type. In this cases innerHTML does not work since XML page is not HTML.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can check the document's content type (eg: `document.contentType === 'text/html'`) or the doc type name (eg: `document.doctype.name === 'html'`).

Comment: Use document.createElementNS.

Comment: thank you! @Titus contentType worked for my issue.